# How to select multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have made a script where i can give a div a backgroundcolor by clicking on one of the td tag in the table. the problem is, i want to give more divs a color.

with getElementById() it can only select one div and not 2.

my CSS:

```
td {width:20px; height:20px;}
.result{width:200px; height:100px; margin:10px auto; background:green;}
```

my script:

```
function bgcolor(color){
        els = document.getElementByClassName('result');
        for(i in els){
            els[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
```

my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background:red;" onclick="bgcolor('red')"></td><td style="background:blue;" onclick="bgcolor('blue')"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background:green;" onclick="bgcolor('green')"></td><td style="background:yellow;" onclick="bgcolor('yellow')"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row">
        <td style="background:brown;" onclick="bgcolor('brown')"></td><td style="background:grey;" onclick="bgcolor('grey')"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="result"></div>
```

what have i done wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just create one function and pass the color as a parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing background color of all elements with the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307163/changing-background-color-of-all-elements-with-the-same-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one function to change the color, use the parameter to specify which color. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, so you'll need to loop through the collection and apply the background color each time:

```
function bgcolor(color){
  els = document.getElementsByClassName('result');
  for(i in els){
    els[i].style.backgroundColor = color
  }
}
```

Then call it with

```
bgcolor('red');
```

Comment: it doesn't work. chrome said:Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByClassName'

Comment: it works! but Chrome is still saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined. what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

you call `getElementByClassName(classname)` which return the **first element** with the specified  class, if you want all the elements you have to do `document.getElementsByClassName(classname)` (elements is plural)

Comment: There's no such function as `getElementByClass`.

Comment: Too fast to type it's getElementsByClassName(classnames) I just edit my answer

Comment: There's no `getElementByClassName()`, either. There's no function that just returns the first element with the specified class. The only function that returns a single element is `getElementById`.

Comment: you're right, my mistake... Indeed in GetElementsByClassName() elements is plural...

Answer (score 0):

first of all use document.getElementsByClassName.