# DataTables hide/show hidden column button CSS style

Tags: html, css, asp.net, datatables, background-color

I'm using

```
<th class="none"></th>
```

to hide the last column in datatable table. Datatable creates a button in the first column to show/hide this column in a child row. The colors of this button are set in responsive.bootstrap.min.css:

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>td:first-child:before{ background-color:#5d9cec }
```

I added a custom class the first column as to disable the button depending on data in row:

```
.not-active { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; }
```

I set the class via C# depending on the content of certain rows.

```
<tr><td class='<%# DisableLink(Eval("InvoiceDate").ToString()) %>'><%# Eval("InvoiceNumber")%></td>
```

*All this is working as expected.*

What I want to do now is set ***the background color of the button to grey when the td's class is set to .not-active***, over writing background-color.

I have tried

```
.not-active > table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>td:first-child:before{ background-color:#5d9cec }
```

and dozen of different combinations but can't seem to get the format correctly.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Adding FSFiddle as requested: https://jsfiddle.net/yk06fbxa/3/

Comment: Can u post a fiddle link?

Comment: @PriyaPayyavula https://jsfiddle.net/yk06fbxa/3/ Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming you are looking for something similar to the below solution.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307163/changing-background-color-of-all-elements-with-the-same-class

Comment: Visited the JSFiddle for that solution, but it doesn't seem to run correctly. That being said, I think something like that could work. However, not sure how to translated to my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS rule that sets the background-color is

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed tbody td:first-child:before, 
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed tbody th:first-child:before {
    ...
    background-color: #31b131;
}
```

To override this when the `<td>` has the class `not-active` you can modify it like that:

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed tbody td.not-active:first-child:before,
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed tbody th.not-active:first-child:before
{
    background-color:#dddddd;
}
```

See a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/poL8t5oz/). I have set the td of the first row not to have the `not-active` class to make sure that it only works with the `.not-active` class.