# Changing Attribute Using Class Name

Tags: javascript, css, attributes

I want to change an attribute using this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('a').setAttribute("color","red")
```

but this does not work in Chrome. The console told me

> setAttribute is not a function

Can you please tell me what javascript function to use? Thank you.

Comment: This will help you to find out the answer to your query. [Changing background color of all elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307163/changing-background-color-of-all-elements-with-the-same-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns an array-like object not a single element. You need to access the indexed item. Also set attibute `style` instead of `color`. If you have more than one element, you can use loop to iterate over the array-like object and set the attributes.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].setAttribute("style","color:red")
------------------------------------^^^----------------------------
```

Code example

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].setAttribute("style","color: red");
```

```html
<p class='a'>Test 1</p>
<p>Test 2</p>
```

With many elements

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('a'), 
                             item => item.setAttribute("style","color: red"));
```

```html
<p class='a'>Test 1</p>
<p class='a'>Test 2</p>
<p>Test 3</p>
```

Comment: What can I do if I want to change the color of all elements with the class 'a'?

Comment: See the below part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) out.

you can try like this `document.getElementsByClassName('.a').style.color = "red";`

I think this is you want.